# where in the file system is Silverlight Isolated storage kept?

Tags: silverlight

I am testing a Silverlight application which stores user info in isolated storage.  I want to "reset" the app and clear out the storage, without doing this in .NET code.
Is there a way to locate and remove these files?  User- and application-specific deletion would be ideal, but full-out clearing is acceptable too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [this article](http://franksworld.com/blog/archive/2010/01/16/11833.aspx) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx):

Windows 7 and Windows Vista

```
%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Silverlight\is
```

Windows XP

```
%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Silverlight\is
```

MacOS

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Application/Support/Microsoft/Silverlight/is
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to clear the info without coding anything, just use the Silverlight control panel, it has a storage tab which allows you to see and remove per application/site.

One easy way to get to it: right click on any Silverlight application => Silverlight.

Or, on my machine, the corresponding application: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\5.1.10411.0\Silverlight.Configuration.exe"