# Is it possible to display IsolatedStorage path in silverlight5

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, isolatedstorage

Could you please tell me is there any way to display Isolated-storage path using In-browser type silverlight5 application.

Answer (score 1):

The full path to the isolated storage is normally not programmatically retrievable, at least not in Silverlight.

It is not possible to access `m_AppFilesPath` member in the `IsolatedStorageFile` instance through reflection, since the field is `private`. If you try to do this, you are likely to receive `FieldAccessException`.

If you are looking for the file system location of the isolated storage files and directories, please read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9473343/650012).

If you want to find out the file paths relative to the isolated storage root when running your application, AFAIK there is only the [GetFileNames methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getfilenames%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in the [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class, preferably in combination with [GetDirectoryNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getdirectorynames%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

It is in principle possible to request the relative file path of a specific file as well by accessing the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.name%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of the [IsolatedStorageFileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getdirectorynames%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) object, however this property is only available in trusted applications.

Comment: Hi Anders
 Thank you for your answer but what i am doing is, i am trying to display IsolatedStoarge path in Textblock as given below.
 var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Captured_Images_Loc, imgnm);
 FieldInfo fi = isoStore.GetType().GetField("m_AppFilesPath", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
 StorageAddress.Text = StorageAddress.Text + (string)fi.GetValue(isoStore);
 Here StorageAddress is TextBlock. while i am trying to assign isolatedStoaregPath into TextBlock it returns System.FieldAccessException exception

Comment: Isn't your problem a *reflection* issue, rather than a *IsolatedStorage* one?

Comment: Most likely, you get `FieldAccessException` because you are not allowed to access `m_AppFilesPath` through reflection. If you look at the `FieldInfo.GetValue` example in the [MSDN Silverlight documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue(v=vs.95).aspx), you will see that `private` fields normally throws the `FieldAccessException`.

Comment: Thank you Anders and jv42 for your help. So from your answers, i thought that there is no way to display IsolatedStorage path of a file. Please let me know whether my assumption is correct or not?

Comment: @skumar I have updated the response. Please consider to accept it as the correct answer if it reasonably answers your question. Please also consider to accept [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390491/unhandledexception-while-fetching-a-dll-from-isolated-storage-in-silverlight5) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220327/how-to-save-an-image-in-bitmap-format-along-with-rectangle-which-is-drawn-on-tha) answers if they have been of sufficient help.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to get the isolated storage location in a WPF app?  I'm having problems with a customer using VDI (Virtual Desktop Infrastructure).  Sometimes the isolated storeage will work and sometimes it doesn't.  Seems like it's random and I want to try to debug this.
They're using a roaming user account.